# ContentControl with Silverlight and Prism

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism

I have a problem with a ContentControl in Silverlight. The ContentControl displays its region only the first time I access to the view. The others times, it displays anything unless I refresh the page.

Here is the xaml code

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="contentControl" />
</Grid>
```

and the code behind :

```
public Staff()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Title = ApplicationStrings.StaffPageTitle;

        IRegionManager regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
        if (!regionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName(_moduleName))
        {
            RegionManager.SetRegionManager(contentControl, regionManager);
            RegionManager.SetRegionName(contentControl, _moduleName);
        }
}
```

If I try to set the region each time, an error is thrown saying that the module already exists.

What should I do, to display the module each time I access to the view?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/11/dynamic-module-loading-with-silverlight.html) out. (start reading from **ADAPTING TO THE REGION**). Inside is a reference to [John Papa](http://www.johnpapa.net/fill-my-prism-region-please/)'s blog. Check that out as well.

Hope it helps you out.